# Find an equation of the tangent line to this parametric curve

Tags: calculus, parametric, tangent-line

I am trying to solve this problem:

Find an equation of the tangent line to the curve $x=t^3 +5, y=t^2 +3$ at the point corresponding to $t=1$.

Here is my work (which is wrong according the the online submittion software)
First I need a point $(x,y)$. So I plug $t=1$ in the parametric equations to get $x=6$ and $y=4$.

Next, I need $m$, the slope. So I follow the formula $$(dy/dt)/(dx/dt)$$ and I end up with $2t/3t^2$ which simplifies to $2/3t$. I plug in $t=1$ and get $2/3$ for my slope. Then I simply plug my point $(6,4)$ and my $m$ into the tangent line equation $$y_1 - y=m(x_1 -x)$$My answer is therefore $$y=2/3(x-6)+4$$But apparently that answer is wrong. Any ideas why?

Comment: Where did that $1/2$ in the last step come from?

Comment: Was a typo. Thanks.

Comment: The online software probably wanted the answer in the form $y=mx+b$ in which case the answer it wanted was $y=\frac{2}{3}x$.

Comment: Your work is correct for the curve as given. One possibility is, a single line has infinitely many correct equations. Another is that the original question was copied incorrectly. Do you know "the answer is wrong" because an automated software system doesn't accept it as correct, or for some other reason...?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales That might be the case. I can not check at the moment, but thanks for the input.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I am using WebWork, and it is telling me that the answer is wrong. However, from what I gathered from the comments, I believe the software is bugged.

Comment: If I recall correctly, WebWork checks for equivalent answers by performing a number of numerical substitutions into the student's answer and checking against what should be the correct numerical results.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be better to consider the parametric curve $r(t) = (t^3 + 5,t^2 + 3)$. Then, the tangent vector to the curve at $t = 1$ will be $r'(1)$. With that in mind, $r'(t) = (3 t^2, 2t)$ and $r'(1) = (3,2)$. As you said, we need the point at $t=1$, which is $(6,4)$. Now, we just need the equation of a line that passes through $(6,4)$ with direction $(3,2)$:
$$L(t) = (6,4) + t(3,2)$$